# Rails 3, Awesome Nested Set, undefined method `parent_id_changed?' for #<Post:0x56f87d0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested, nested-sets

I've installed Awesome Nested Set, but something weird happens when I try to create any object that has acts_as_nested_set.

```
 undefined method `parent_id_changed?' for #<Post:0x5671830>
```

in this line:

```
 @post = Post.create!(params[:post])
```

Similarly, I get undefined method `parent_id_changed?' for comments and nested comments:

```
 @comment = Comment.create!(params[:comment])
 @comment.move_to_child_of(@post)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a field called `parent_id` on the `comments` table.

Comment: ah, but it's on the CreateComments and CreatePosts file,

    t.integer :parent_id

Comment: i fixed it by making an AddFooToBar type migration